# Residue calculation complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I started to calculate an integral $\int_{|z| = 106} \cos\left(\frac{1}{6z+1}\left(\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)\cdots(z-105)}\right)\right)\,dz$. I think that a good way is to think about $\infty$ as a singular point and investigate its type. If I put $\infty$ to the equation, I will get a zero, so its type is zero. And now I need use this technique to calculate the integral.

Comment: Just a thought, but maybe you can use $\cos(1/f(z))=1-\frac{1}{2f(x)^2}+\cdots$.

Comment: It looks interesting. We asked teacher nd he said that first of all we should find out a type of singularity $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [residue-at-infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) is the simplest approach (not sure how *you* do it).

The same is done by $z=1/w$: the given integral is $$\int_{|w|=1/n}\cos\left(\frac{w}{6+w}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{w}{1-kw}\right)\frac{dw}{w^2}\qquad(n=106)$$ ($dz=\color{red}{-}dw/w^2$ is compensated by the change of orientation of the contour).

Hence, it is $2\pi\mathrm{i}f'(0)$ where $f(w)$ is the cosine above. And the result is clearly zero.